# Join Two Tables Where Difference Between Unique Identifier Key Is 1

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to join two tables where the unique identifying key is a difference of 1. Take for instance table A and B below:

```
Table A
+-----+-------+--------+
| Key | Check | Amount | 
+-----+-------+--------+
|  23 |   3   | $600   | 
|  46 |   72  | $2043  | 
|  67 |   4   | $99    | 
|  85 |   16  | $1     | 
+-----+-------+--------+
```

```
Table B
+-----+-------+------+
| Key |  Seq  | Flag | 
+-----+-------+------+
|  24 |  546  |  Y   | 
|  47 |  254  |  Y   |  
|  68 |  687  |  N   | 
|  86 |  3475 |  Y   | 
+-----+-------+------+
```

The Key column should join both tables together, but are separated by a difference of 1 value. In table A, Key 23 should join on Table B's Key 24. So, 23 + 1 = 24. For Table A 46, the Key in B is 47 so 46 + 1 = 47 etc.

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use a proper ON clause  for join

```
select A.*, B.*
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN  TableB B On A.key +1 = B.key
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct solution;

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN  TableB B On A.key  = B.key - 1;
```